# Localization for guest users

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to make site localization for guests.

How can I do it?

I am wondering how to set guest's language for all pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do it in the code, I don't think there's a way in the config of the Site itself.

Modify all your Site pages to include [language](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_page.htm) param, for example

```
<apex:page
    standardStylesheets="false"
    showHeader="false"
    language="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.l}">
```

And then you'll need somehow (picklist on the site? cookie?) set the parameter in the URL to for example `l=en_US`, `l=fr`, `l=nl` etc.

Comment: Thanks. I've read this but it's not acceptable. Beacause I want to store language after user picked it. I would be awesome if I could retrieve coockie inside expression {!..} or even call some static method which will retrieve cockie.

Comment: In the PageReference class you have getCookies() method. On lang selection you could set the cookie. If your sites share one controller / controller extension - add a variable there and reference this variable in expression on the page? If you don't want them to share 1 extension - simply copy over cookie-checking code into each class.

Comment: Any way of hooking that up for standard pages, or only Visualforce?

Comment: @MikeChale - you mean "en_US" user views standard page or a report and you'd want to show it in "fr" without Visualforce? No idea, never seen such thing and never needed one really. Maybe some sidebar hacks that'd sniff which page you're at, temporarily update User record, refresh the page... Messy.